# Access type params from puppet provider

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to create a perforce custom type *devtrack* but am stuck in the prefetch stage. There I am trying to use my instances class method to find the correct provider

```
def self.prefetch(resources)
    instances.each do |prov|
        if resource = resources[prov.name]
            resource.provider = prov
        end
    end
end
```

and in the instances class method I try to find all clients on the current host by using the command

> p4 workspaces -u

using the below code

```
def self.get_list_of_workspaces_on_host(host)       
    ws_strs = p4(['workspaces', '-u', <USERNAME>]).split("\n")
    ws_strs.select { |str| str.include?(host) }.map{ |ws| ws.split[1] }
end

def self.get_workspace_properties(ws)
    md = /^(\w*)_.*_(main|\d{2})_managed$/.match(ws)
    ws_props = {}
    ws_props[:ensure]    = :present
    ...
    ws_props
end

def self.instances
    host = `hostname`.strip
    get_list_of_workspaces_on_host(host).collect do |ws|
        ws_props = get_workspace_properties(ws)
        new(ws_props)
    end
end
```

and the p4 command is defined like

```
has_command(:p4, "/usr/bin/p4") do
    environment :P4PORT => <PERFORCE SERVER>, :P4USER => <USERNAME>
end
```

The problem I have is that for any p4 command to work I need to access the server, this is specified in the type

```
devtrack { '36': source  => '<PERFORCE SERVER>'}
```

but how can I access this value from prefetch? The problem beeing that prefetch is a class method and thus can not access the **@properties_hash** or the **resource** hash. Is there a way to get around this? Am I designing this completely wrong?

Comment: Not all resource types can support prefetching.  It sounds like yours is one that can't.

Comment: yeah, that would be an option, then just using the instances for *puppet resource ...* cmd. Should be able to use ENV in that case, it's always host local that command, right? But, would really like to use the flush way of updating the hosts, is that still possible without the property_hash IS values?

Comment: By the time you are ready to flush, each provider instance should have its `@resource` available.  That provides all the information available from the catalog as to the identity and desired properties of the resource.  If you need more than that in order to update the resource then you can read it at flush time.  Presumably the resource instances carry enough information for that -- otherwise your approach is fatally flawed.

Comment: Thats right, it should work with flush. Thanks for your help John